# Underscore behavior with Bind

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Reading through the source at:
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js

This is the _bind method so frequently used (I've removed the native check for clarity)

```
   _.bind = function(func, obj) {
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return function() {
      return func.apply(obj, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
    };
  };
```

The args that get passed func.apply seems unnecessarily duplicated at the end

An example using Node interpreter (remove last line to try in Firebug etc..)

```
var arguments = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
var appliedArgs = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
require('sys').puts(appliedArgs);
```

This outputs:

```
3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I highly doubt I've found a bug but confused as to why its working this way, why append the args again in such fashion. Confused

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bind method returns a closure, which can accept additional arguments to be passed to the function. The two references to `arguments` in the underscore code do not refer to the same set of arguments. The first is from the enclosing function, and the second is from the returned closure. Here is a slightly modified version of this method, which hopefully makes it clearer:

```
_.bind = function(func, obj /*, arg1, arg2 ... argN */) {

  // Prepare default arguments for currying, removing
  // the function and object references
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

  // Return a closure that has access to the parent scope
  return function(/* arg1, arg2 ... argN */) {

    // Prepare arguments that are passed when bound
    // method is called
    var args2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    // Curry the method with the arguments passed
    // to the enclosing function and those passed
    // to the bound method
    return func.apply(obj, args.concat(args2));

  }
```

This essentially allows you to curry a method when it is bound to an object. An example of its usage would be:

```
var myObj = {},
    myFunc = function() {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    };

myObj.newFunc = _.bind(myFunc, myObj, 1, 2, 3);

>>> myObj.newFunc(4, 5, 6);
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks gary. I missed that, makes sense now.

Comment: No problem. If you're trying to get a feel for the Underscore source code, they also provide an annotated version - http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html

Answer (score 1):

The call to `_bind` binds an object and some arguments to a method. You can pass additional arguments to the bound method when you invoke it. You wouldn't likely pass the same arguments twice. Usage is:

```
function sum() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        total += arguments[i];
    }
    return total;
}
var sumsome = _bind(sum, {}, 1, 2, 3);
sumsome(4,5,6); // equivalent to the call ({summ: sum}).summ(1,2,3,4,5,6)
sumsome('a','b','c'); // equivalent to the call ({summ: sum}).summ(1,2,3,'a','b','c')
```